# Generate sql select statements with data from another table

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

Problem: I have a table, lets call it AllColumns with the attributes (TableName, ColumnName) among others.

Now, what i want to achieve is to generate a select Statement for each record of this table.

In Pseudocode:

```
for (table, column) in (select TableName, ColumnName from AllColumns) do
  select 'table', column from table where column like '%blah%'
end for
```

Can you help?

Comment: You need dynamic SQL to do this.  Are you familiar with `sp_executesql` or `exec()`.  If not, you can start by google'ing "sql server dynamic sql".

Comment: Or, if you are just trying to generate something to save yourself from typing everything out (and not trying to make an automated, rerunnable script that does the work for you), you can use the `PRINT` command to output the values to the Messages pane and then copy/paste it into a new window and run from there.

Comment: Isn't there something like Postgres `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.tables` ?

Comment: Use `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS` for the table name and columns. `SELECT TABLE_CATALOG, TABLE_SCHEMA, TABLE_NAME, COLUMN_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE COLUMN_NAME LIKE '%blah%'`

Comment: All hints do not seem to be a solution: I dont Need INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS. I have an own table with These Information (AllColumns). TableName and ColumnName in AllColumns all exist in the database. So i can theoretically create a select Statement with like "select '<TableName>', <ColumnName> from <TableName> where ..." where <TableName> and <ColumnName> is filled with every entry in AllColumns one by one. AllColumns has thousands of entries.

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of a `WHILE` loop and a temporary table. So you fetch all the records into a temp table and then loop through the records to perform you select or any process you wish to execute, as follows;

```
DECLARE @TempTable TABLE 
(
    ID INT IDENTITY(1,1),
    Table Varchar(100),
    Column Varchar(100)
)

INSERT INTO @TempTable 
    SELECT Table, Column FROM AllColumns 


 DECLARE @LOOP INT
 DECLARE @COUNT INT

 SET @LOOP = 0
 SET @COUN = 1

 SELECT @LOOP = COUNT(1) FROM @TempTable 

WHILE @COUNT <= @LOOP 
    BEGIN

     select 'table', column from @TempTable 
     where column like '%blah%'
     and ID = @COUNT 

SET @COUNT  = @COUNT  + 1
END
```

Answer (score 0):

You *can* do this with dynamic SQL:

```
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX);

SET @SQL = (SELECT  'SELECT [Table] = ''' + TableName + ''', ' + 
                    '       [Column] = ''' + ColumnName + ''' ' + 
                    'FROM   ' + TableName +  ' ' +
                    'WHERE  ' + ColumnName + ' LIKE ''%blah%'';'
            FROM    AllColumns
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)');

EXECUTE sp_executesql @SQL;
```

However, just because you *can* do something, doesn't mean you *should* - you have said that AllColumns has thousands of entries, you are therefore running thousands of short queries, each of which generating it's own result set. I can't think of many scenarios where this is desirable.